# How to prepare CSV file for AutoML entity extraction from GCP?

Tags: google-cloud-platform, google-cloud-storage, google-cloud-automl, google-natural-language

I have created Jsonl files and formats specified by google. I uploaded the files to the Cloud Storage.

I prepared a CSV file, first column has path to Jsonl file(gs://*example/file.jsonl), second column has 'TRAIN' or 'VALIDATE' or 'TEST'.

I got an error saying 'Cannot find the referenced file: TRAIN in request.'

How to prepare CSV file?

Comment: how did you created the jsonl files?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Souds like you have the column order backwards. The order of the columns should be "ML Use" first, then GCS URI second. See the example CSV file from the Quickstart:

https://cloud.google.com/natural-language/automl/entity-analysis/docs/quickstart

gs://cloud-ml-data/NL-entity/dataset.csv

https://console.cloud.google.com/storage/browser/cloud-ml-data/NL-entity/?_ga=2.132412110.-1530629862.1558449111

```
$ cat Downloads/NL-entity_dataset.csv 
TRAIN,gs://cloud-ml-data/NL-entity/train.jsonl
TEST,gs://cloud-ml-data/NL-entity/test.jsonl
VALIDATION,gs://cloud-ml-data/NL-entity/validation.jsonl
```

Comment: Thank you. I was bit confused just from reading from the quick start. Example really helped.